# Using PHP's SoapClient, how to deserialize SOAP responses into a custom class?

Tags: php, soap-client, xml-deserialization

I have a PHP Web application that consumes a Web Service using PHP's native `SoapClient` class. By default, `SoapClient` deserializes the Web Service's SOAP responses into `stdClass` objects. I would like to override this default. How can I do that?

Comment: See if the [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) manual page helps, specificity under _options_ and look for _classmap_.

Comment: @Tim: The example given using the `classmap` option is too simple. I would like to specify a class that performs some data correction tasks at construction time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SoapClient's __getLastResponse() method to get the raw XML response back as a string instead of an object.

Additionally you can overwrite it's do request method by extending the SoapClient class.